# What font is this in Hangouts app?

Tags: font-identification

It's something like a script type of font. I tried to use the myfont font finder but it didn't recognize its cursive like font :( Anyone knows?

[image]

Comment: Looks hand written to me.

Comment: Ouch, any other ideas? :/

Comment: It's going to be hard to pinpoint it with just those two letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's custom made, but you can find similar fonts if you look for handwritten, calligraphy or 'school', for example:

[**Simple Ronde**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/jbfoundry/simple-ronde/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old, but I was just looking for this same font. Not sure if I found it exactly, but this page has some similar fonts if you're still in search for that font. 
http://www.createcraftlove.com/cursive-fonts/